# How to query based on related table without returning records from related table

Tags: sql-server

**Table_A**

```
^ID^Name^
|1 |Joe |
|2 |Jane|
```

**Table_B**

```
^ID^Foreign_ID^Company  ^Specialty^
|1 |1         |Microsoft|SQL      |
|2 |1         |Microsoft|PHP      |
|3 |2         |Oracle   |SQL      |
|4 |2         |Oracle   |HTML5    |
```

The query:

```
SELECT Name, Company
FROM   Table_A
         LEFT JOIN Table_B
         ON Table_A.ID = Table_B.Foreign_ID
WHERE  Table_B = 'Microsoft'
```

Say I'm formatting a report, and I'm only interested in employee's that work at Microsoft and I only want 1 record per employee, how do I prevent the `Speciality` column in Table_B from creating multiple rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a join, since you have no columns from `table_B` in the output. You could use a semi-join, i.e an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT a.Name, 'Microsoft' AS Company
FROM Table_A AS a
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Table_B AS b
        WHERE a.ID = b.Foreign_ID
          AND b.Company = 'Microsoft'
      ) ;
```

If you did want some other column from `table_B` (say the `Specialty`) and still only 1 row, you could use either a derived table with a window function, or `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP 1`. `CROSS APPLY` is a special join where we can reference previous tables. Note that it's similar to `INNER JOIN` (you had `LEFT JOIN` while you need `INNER JOIN`):

```
SELECT a.Name, 'Microsoft' AS Company, b.Specialty
FROM Table_A AS a
  CROSS APPLY 
    ( SELECT TOP (1) bi.Specialty 
      FROM Table_B AS bi
      WHERE a.ID = bi.Foreign_ID
        AND b.Company = 'Microsoft'
      ORDER BY Specialty 
    ) AS b ;
```

Comment: For my purposes, this method worked better, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The where was killing the left join
Just need distinct

```
SELECT distinct Name, Company
FROM Table_A
JOIN Table_B
  ON Table_A.ID = Table_B.Foreign_ID
 AND Table_B.Company = 'Microsoft'
```

Comment: Good one as well. The only possible issue would be if thee are employees with same name. They would be returned as 1 row instead of many. No idea what the OP wants in that case.